# How to Pick a Journal for Publishing a Research Work?

Tags: estimation, self-study, research

I got my MS in EE way back in 1994 and have not presented at a conference, or published in a journal before, but I had and still have an intense interest in the applied math that I learned. I have been working my own research project for a few years, and I want to publish a paper on my work. What I did is develop an algorithm similar to a discrete Kalman fiter, and it gives better estimates under certain conditions. I am looking for advice on what journal would a good choice. It would take to long for me to learn LaTeX (is that what it's called), and I don't have the education needed to develop the sophisticated math that I see in many journals.

Comment: Microsoft Word is easier than LaTeX, can do pretty equations, has edit tracking for collaboration and review, and is accepted by most journals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting work published in a high impact factor journal is quite a slog. If you're starting from not having presented at a conference etc. before, that's going to be an even bigger ask.

However, it's not impossible.

For IEEE journals, short notes about signal processing topics [can be sent to the *IEEE Signal Processing Letters* journal](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=97).

However, starting there might be too much.

What I'd suggest is to look at starting with an online journal such as [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/) or [PLOSone](http://www.plosone.org/).

Even before submitting there, I'd suggest posting a question here that might be relevant to the situations where the algorithm might be better than others, and also posting an answer with your algorithm.

The aim with any of these submissions is to get feedback about your work and improve it or its presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please elaborate on why you would like to publish in a journal? One reason is that your work will be checked (hopefully) by competent reviewers and could be strengthened. @Peter K [IEEE Signal Processing Letters](http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org/publications/periodicals/letters/) suggestion is excellent, as per publication you can as well apply with the same paper to conferences like ICASSP or GlobalSIP (see section Scope in the above link). [IET Signal Processing](http://digital-library.theiet.org/content/journals/iet-spr) is another option, possibly less selective. There are many other choices, depending on your goal.

You can as well find a neat application, and publish in an applied journal instead of a pure signal processing that may require proofs.

A well written technical note with clean code is a final option, and can be cited as well.

Comment: I am open to presenting at a conference. What are the pros & cons of a conference vs a journal. One thing I want to do is make it easy for others implement & evaluate my algorithm while getting credit for it.

Comment: The real question is why (since you do not publish on a standard basis): share, develop collaborations, get credit, earn fame, be recognized, prove something, improve...? And at what price: time, work, money (I understand no LaTeX, and no maths)? Depending on the order of priorities, a strategy could be devised.